# Docker container deployed in Linux environment

Tags: docker, localhost

This is what I'm trying to do. I have created a docker container and have it deployed in my Linux Putty environment. I am now trying to view the website I deployed on my Windows Chrome browser. When I try accessing localhost upon running the container, I am getting "This site can't be reached". Below is the command I used to run the container:

```
docker run -d --name testContainer -p 80:80 static-app:v1
```

Any advice on how I can access this would be helpful.

Comment: More details would definitely help such as what port specified in your docker command? on the browser are you trying to access via the port? e.g: http://localhost:<port> . Would help if you provide the command you ran as well.

Comment: My apologies. I've edited with the command I ran to start the container. I had tried to access outside my Linux Putty session on Google Chrome browser on Windows with "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming these two words as

1- Linux putty environment: Linux VM running on windows( oracle etc..) you connected this through putty

2- website I deployed on my Windows Chrome browser: trying to access container through chrome as port is exposed

if above mentioned case is correct then:

port exposed is between host and container is 80:80, here host mean where your docker is running, in your case its  Linux environment. you can not see that on windows chrome browser.

Specify if the situation is different.

Comment: I've figured it out. My Linux putty instance is hosted in the cloud. After running the docker container, I was able to access my instance IP and access the container.